# Mr Beer sells Brew Max

Tags: original-gravity, alcohol-content

Does anyone know what Mr Beer Brew Max is? Also what can be substituted for it?I am trying to raise my A.B.V. in my home brew. I ask because I need a substitute. It almost looks like very small pieces of Rock Candy. When add to my wort it seemed to thicken it. Also don't know what kind of effect it has on A.B.V. or the taste of the Beer. The 
 batch I used it in is cold fermenting now in my fridge.

Comment: This thing? https://www.mrbeer.com/mrbeer-booster. I'd suppose a mix of plain sugar and DME at some ratio depending on how much unfermentables are really in there would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Coopers sell a beer enhancer that is composed of a mix of glucose and light dried malt extract. It adds body (via non fermentables in the extract) and increases alcoholic strength via the sugar and fermentables in the extract. I imagine that "BrewMax" is something similar.

One can usually tell the difference between just glucose/sugar and dried malt extract by colour (sugar is white - extract is light brown) and the reaction with water. Dried extract becomes ridiculously sticky if a (very) little water is added.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely just a monosaccharide. (simplest form of sugar)

Corn Sugar is the go-to monosaccharide in brewing and can be bought at your LHBS.